# PostgreSQL: Date Calendar Days Interval Scenario

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I would like to print this table (displaying only 4 rows for brevity):

| Dates | Period |
| --- | --- |
| 01-MAR-2022 | 61 |
| 02-MAR-2022 | 61 |
| 03-MAR-2022 | 61 |
| 30-APR-2022 | 61 |

So far I have:

```
SELECT CAST(TRUNC(date_trunc('month',CURRENT_DATE) + interval '-2 month') AS DATE) + (n || 'day')::INTERVAL AS Dates
, date_trunc('month',CURRENT_DATE) + interval '-2 month' + INTERVAL '2 month' - date_trunc('month',CURRENT_DATE) + interval '-2 month' AS Period
FROM generate_series(0,61) n
```

Please help with a better way of generating the period and also replacing the hard-coded 61 in generate_series(0,61).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you actually trying to accomplish, it is not clear nor specified. BTW your query is invalid. It appears you looking to list each data from first date of 2 months prior to the last date of 1 month prior and the total number of days in that range. The following would give the first date, and using date subtraction gives the number of days.

```
with full_range( first_dt, num_days) as 
     ( select  date_trunc ('month', (current_date - interval '2 months'))::date
            ,  date_trunc ('month', (current_date - interval '1 day'))::date - 
               date_trunc ('month', (current_date - interval '2 months'))::date
     ) 
select * 
  from full_range;
```

With that in hand you can use the num_days with generate series with the expression

```
select generate_series(0, num_days-1) from full_range
```

Finally combine the above arriving at: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9ce04f4fd3c916c955b5867e09301e6c))

```
with full_range( first_dt, num_days) as 
     ( select  date_trunc ('month', (current_date - interval '2 months'))::date
            ,  date_trunc ('month', (current_date - interval '1 day'))::date - 
               date_trunc ('month', (current_date - interval '2 months'))::date
     ) 
select (first_dt + n*interval '1 day')::date, num_days
  from full_range
  cross join (select generate_series(0, num_days-1) from full_range) gn(n);
```